# How to filter mobile devices by list of e-mail address

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm working with the Google Admin SDK Directory API, more specifically with Mobile Devices. I already used the tool provided by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices/list#try-it) and also created a program using the .Net client library to get all devices with success.

The problem is, I need now to get all the mobile devices filtered by a list of emails. I was able to filter using a single email address like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/ZXXXXX/devices
/mobile?projection=BASIC&query=email:EMAIL_HERE&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

But I couldn't find a way to filter using multiple email values like:

```
query email: email1:@my-domain.com, email2@my-domain.com, email3@my-domain.com
```

The documentation provided [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408863#search) on the Search string format does not specify nor give examples for this case.

**EDIT**: The documentation on the Search String Format does say this:

> To Search within a specific field: enter an operator followed by an
>   argument. For example, user:joesabia. You can use single words or
>   quoted lists of words as an argument when running an operator query.

So, I tried doing something like this in the query box:

```
email:"email1@my-domain,com""email2@my-domain,com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no OR in the query format. You'll need to either use multiple API calls with one email query per call or just list all devices and filter by email locally.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out unfortunately. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple fields search in query string separated by space for example `email=test@example.com name:Test`. But in your case just give it a try doing this `email:test@example.com email:test2@example.com`.